# Regular expression to accept a capital letter should accept a number instead

Tags: regex, bash, system-administration

I have a regular expression which should accept a number in the final M position, but my customer has a letter instead (capital M).

> CNTCST79L20H50`M`G

The regular expression is:

```
^[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]{1}$
```

How could I modify the regular expression so it will accept CNTCST79L20H50`M`G, instead of requiring a number?

is

```
^[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{2}$
```

correct as a regular expression for the code

> CNTCST79L20H50MG?

Edit:

**NOTE** Unfortunately, the final regular expression should accept both cases.

Comment: Your current regex won't accept a digit in this place anymore. Is it what you want? If so congrats, your regex is good. Otherwise you need to stick a character class such as `[0-9A-Za-z]` which will accept either a digit or a letter between the digits and letters classes you've modified (and decrease the quantifier of the letter class back to 1)

Comment: Also a small nitpick : simply write `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[A-Za-z]{1}`, it means the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. You can see it working here: https://regex101.com/r/rHBFnA/1

Updated for your update  :)

You can inidicate both letters and numbers in the character class:

```
^[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z]$
```

That matches both of these:

```
CNTCST79L20H50MG
CNTCST79L20H505G
```

But not this:

```
CNTCST79L20H5057
```

https://regex101.com/r/rHBFnA/4

Comment: @llllIIIIIllllllIIIIIIlllII I've updated accordingly

Comment: @Aaron thanks, I updated my response -- need more coffee

Comment: No worries ! A remaining problem though : the regex now accepts a digit as the last character, which might not be what OP wants.

Comment: @Aaron, I'm glad you're here

Comment: I've already drank my 5 daily coffees ;-) Glad I could help !